# Regularity of Lebesgue measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a Lebesgue measurable set of measure $m(A)=p>0$. Then for all $0<q<p$, show that there is a subset $B\subseteq A$ with $m(B)=q$.

Which Theorem do i have to use here, regularity or density of Lebesgue measure or something else ?

Comment: Look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/88135/8271)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider $f(x) = \int_A 1_{(-\infty, x]}$. Then $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = 0$, $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = p$ and $f$ is continuous.

Then, use the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Why is f continuous ? I think we can't prove it with  $\epsilon-\delta$ criterion ( $m(A)<\delta\Rightarrow\int_{A} \mathbb{1}_{(-\infty,x]}<\epsilon $) because this is precisely the exercise, to show that such a $\delta$ exists.

Comment: No, this is not precisely the exercise. Suppose $x>y$, then $|f(x)-f(y)| = \int_A 1_{(y,x]} \le \int 1_{(y,x]} = |x-y|$. Similarly for $x>y$. Hence $f$ is Lipschitz continuous with rank 1.